# IE position:absolute not working

Tags: internet-explorer, position

I have a class and using css i made position absolute.

`.myClass
{
position:absolute
}`

It is working perfectly in chrome. but there is some issue with internet explorer. Initially working fine but when I reload my page using server side event, it is not working i.e. position is no more absolute. I fixed by using in-line style. I want to know the reason.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

internet explorer have this problem. but you can solve this by using inline styles. 
I noticed this problem doesn't exists in IE11